# Progress Bar Implementation with pure CSS, problem with hover

Tags: html, css, hover, pure-css

I was following [100days of CSS Challenges](https://100dayscss.com/days/62/). Got stuck on 62th day. Trying to implement a progress bar with pure css.

When hovering on cards I want progress bars to have larger width.

Below hover does not work and I dont know why. Any tips on how to debug this kind css problems would also be helpful.

It would be easier with JS but I want pure CSS solutions. Thanks........

```
.basic:hover ~ .stats .users-bar .users-progress {
  transform: scaleX(0.7); 
  width: 5%;
}
```

```css
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-top: -200px;
  margin-left: -200px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #E9EDEF;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 35px 25px 0 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card {
  height: 160px;
  width: 109px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.top {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #7DD0ED;
  color: white;
  font-size: 0.95rem;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.middle {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
}

.price {
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #5E5E5E;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.card p {
  margin: -6px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  color: #333;
}

.lines {
  margin: 15px 0 0 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 33px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}


/* This hover does not work */

.basic:hover ~ .stats .users-bar .users-progress {
  transform: scaleX(0.7);
  width: 5%;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  color: rgb(39, 166, 210);
}

.card:hover .top {
  background-color: rgb(39, 155, 210);
}

.card:hover .price {
  color: rgb(39, 166, 210);
}

.stats {
  width: 375px;
  background-color: white;
  height: 155px;
  margin: 0 0 18px 0;
  box-shadow: 4px 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0 15px 0 15px;
}

.info {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.info p {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #333;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

.bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: #E9EDEF;
  margin: -6px 0 0 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  background-color: #7DD0ED;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.projects-bar {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.as-console-wrapper { height: 300px !important; }
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="cards">
    <div class="card basic" id="basic">
      <div class="top">Basic</div>
      <div class="price">$5</div>
      <p>per month</p>
      <div class="lines">
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 75px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 60px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 70px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 50px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card pro">
      <div class="top">Pro</div>
      <div class="price">$10</div>
      <p>per month</p>
      <div class="lines">
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 75px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 60px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 70px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 50px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card premium">
      <div class="top">Premium</div>
      <div class="price">$20</div>
      <p>per month</p>
      <div class="lines">
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 75px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 60px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 70px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
        <span style="height: 3px; width: 50px; background-color: #E4E4E4;"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="stats">
    <div class="info">
      <p>5 Users</p>
      <p>100 Users</p>
    </div>
    <div class="users-bar bar">
      <div class="users-progress progress" id="users-progress"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>20 GB</p>
      <p>200 GB</p>
    </div>
    <div class="gb-bar bar">
      <div class="gb-progress progress"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <p>1 Project</p>
      <p>50 Projects</p>
    </div>
    <div class="projects-bar bar">
      <div class="projects-progress progress"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to scale progressbar on hover?

Comment: Yes. When hovering on cards I want progress bars to have larger width.

Comment: edit your question and add the above line of your comment, so all can understand what you want

Comment: your css will only work if their parents are same, in your case .basic has parent .cards and .stats is outside of .cards. you have to work around and change your html

Answer (score 1):

use this css instead and change your html accordingly

```
   .basic:hover ~ .stats .users-bar {
      transform: scaleX(0.7);
    }

    .pro:hover ~ .stats .gb-bar {
      transform: scaleX(0.7);
    }

    .premium:hover ~ .stats .projects-bar {
      transform: scaleX(0.7);
    }
```

Comment: Okay this is not possible with pure css with this kind of html structure, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to change the html structure